# Can't load OneToMany-ManyToOne Relationship TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm having difficulties with loading in a OneToMany-ManyToOne relationship. I'm only including the parts that are *truly* effecting in this issue/bug.

`GuildInfraction`:

```
@Entity()
class GuildInfraction extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  guild_id: string;

  @Column()
  moderator_id: string;

  @Column()
  user_id: string;

  @ManyToOne((_) => GuildSettings, (settings) => settings.infractions)
  @JoinColumn()
  guild: GuildSettings;

  @ManyToOne((_) => UserSettings, (settings) => settings.infractions)
  @JoinColumn()
  moderator: UserSettings;

  @ManyToOne((_) => UserSettings, (settings) => settings.infractions)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: UserSettings;
}
```

`GuildSettings`:

```
@Entity()
class GuildSettings extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany((_) => GuildInfraction, (infraction) => infraction.guild, { eager: true })
  infractions: GuildInfraction[];
}
```

`UserSettings`:

```
@Entity()
class UserSettings extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany((_) => GuildInfraction, (infraction) => infraction.user, { eager:true })
  infractions: GuildInfraction[];
}
```

Here is an example of how this is being used, of course I have created my own class managers to use it easier:

```
// Create a guild instance.
const guild = new GuildSettings();
guild.id = "554742955898961930";
guild.infractions = [];
await guild.save();

// Create a user instance.
const user = new UserSettings();
user.id = "389472120981291008";
user.infractions = [];

// Create another user instance.
const moderator = new UserSettings();
moderator.id = "506627462588006400";
moderator.infractions = [];

// Create a infraction instance and attach the previous guild, user, and moderator instances to it.
const infraction = new GuildInfraction();
infraction.guild = guild;
infraction.guild_id = guild.id;
infraction.user = user;
infraction.user_id = user.id;
infraction.moderator = moderator;
infraction.moderator_id = moderator.id;
await infraction.save();
```

Here are examples of attempting to use the connection repository to retrieve the infractions using `getRepository`:

```
// Through the GuildSettings repository.
const connection = getRepository(GuildSettings);
console.log((await connection.findOne("554742955898961930")).infractions); // Returns an empty array: '[]'

// Through the UserSettings repository.
const connection = getRepository(UserSettings);
console.log((await connection.findOne("389472120981291008")).infractions); // Returns an empty array '[]'

// Through the GuildInfraction repository to retrieve the guild.
const connection = getRepository(GuildInfraction);
console.log((await connection.find())[0].guild); // Returns 'undefined'

// Through the GuildInfraction repository to retrieve the user.
const connection = getRepository(GuildInfraction);
console.log((await connection.find())[0].user); // Returns 'undefined'

// Through the GuildInfraction repository to retrieve the moderator.
const connection = getRepository(GuildInfraction);
console.log((await connection.find())[0].moderator); // Returns 'undefined'
```

**Your help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `guild` field in GuildSettings giving you issues? It should throw a 'duplicate column "guild_id"' error IIRC. By the way, in GuildInfraction you have two ManyToOne relations to UserSettings, and the inverse side of the relation is mapped to the same field of the related entity. I'm not sure it's something your orm supports.

Comment: Hmm, I believe I scratched the idea of using relations entirely and am now just going with a giant manager, instance system.